# Are euphemisms more likely to be translated when imported into another language?

Tags: etymology

When euphemisms enter another language, are the words making up the euphemism more likely to be translated to that language compared to non-euphemisms? I suspect that people translate words in the euphemisms to emphasize the euphemisms involved.

From world war 2, the euphemistic term "die Endlösung" entered the English language as "Final solution", and 大東亜共栄圏 entered the English language as "Greater East Asia Co-Prosperity Sphere", whereas blitzkrieg, luftwaffe, kamikaze, and kristallnacht are usually kept in the original German or Japanese. Is this a general trend? (Some of the terms kept in the original language are proper nouns, but presumably that'd also be true of of the terms that got translated into English.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_German_military_terms Some data to prove the hypothesis